# Model for pre-stressed string under transverse load

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Can any one explain me how the equation

$$-Hu''(x) = F(x)$$

(found on this [site](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensFunction.html)), which is governing differential equation for prestressed strings under a transverse load $p(x)$ was obtained?

Comment: You should always copy down relevant portions of the link you are referring to. Our aim is to make each question useful not only for the person who asks, but also for the public on the Web who may get to see this Web page through search engines. Links to Web pages may be broken in future or not exist at all, whereby the question will become useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: prestressed rope under lateral force]

The question is how to derive the differential equation $-Hu^{\prime\prime}(x)=F(x)$. Note that their diagram is problematic; it suggests that $F$ is a single force, whereas it is actually a distributed force (with units of force per unit distance).

Draw a free-body diagram of an infinitesimal segment of the rope in which the angle changes from $\theta(x)$ (left side) to $\theta(x+dx)$ (right side). The tension $H$ acts parallel to the rope; thus, the direction of $H$ (but not its magnitude) also differs between the left and right sides. We're going to set the $y$-direction component of this difference equal to the $y$-direction lateral force distribution $F(x)$ applied over $dx$ to obtain mechanical equilibrium in the $y$-direction:
$$-H\sin\theta(x)-F(x)\,dx+H\sin\theta(x+dx)=0$$

Assume small angles so that $\theta\approx\sin\theta\approx\tan\theta\approx\frac{du(x)}{dx}$, all that good stuff.

Taylor expand $\theta(x+dx)$ to first order to approximate it as $\theta(x)+\frac{d\theta}{dx}dx$.

This gives $-H\frac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2}=F(x)$ immediately.